# Run SUID C scripts under Apache

Tags: c, linux, apache, suid

i have a cgi script in c the same as this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

int main(void) {

    printf("Content-type: text/html\n\n");

    printf("RUID : %d<br />\n", getuid());
    printf("EUID : %d<br />\n", geteuid());

    char ch;
    char getLine[256];
    char *token = NULL;
    FILE *ft;

    ft = fopen("/etc/shadow", "r");
    if(ft == NULL){
        printf("%s", "can not open file");
        exit(1);
    }
    while(1){
        ch=fgetc(ft);
        if(ch == EOF)
            break;
        else if(ch == '\n'){
            token = (char *)strtok(getLine, ":");
            printf("<b> fitst toke : %s</b><br />\n", token);
            if(strcmp(token,"root") == 0){
                token = (char *)strtok(NULL, ":");
                printf("password is : %s<br />\n", token);
                break;
            }
        } else{
            sprintf(getLine, "%s%c", getLine, ch);
        }
    }

  return 0;
}
```

after compile and set SUID:

```
chmod a+s ./mycode
```

if run this in shell, every thing seem okay :

```
Content-type: text/html

RUID : 500<br />
EUID : 0<br />
<b> fitst toke : root</b><br />
password is : $1$aLRBTUSe$341xIb6AlUeOlrtRdWGY40<br />
```

but if run it under apache and in cgi-bin, he say, can not open file. although the EUID seem to be okay :

```
RUID : 48<br />
EUID : 0<br />
can not open file
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try also printing the value of `errno` after the `fopen()` fails, to see what the problem is.

Comment: Error opening file: Permission denied.

Comment: return of this code : printf( "Error opening file: %s\n", strerror( errno ) );

Comment: From a security standpoint, this is a really stupid idea.

Comment: this program before start it's process has an authentication from remote server for tokens and other authorize solution same as a fixed ip and port in iptables. with all of this process, can this code have security bugs?

Comment: Is there any legitimate reason to do this? If you want to authenticate someone against `/etc/shadow`, I'm sure apache has modules that do the authentication, don't tell the outside world the hashes (just whether the authentication succeeded), and implement appropriate timing to slow down brute force attacks.

Comment: i.e. there is a reason why you had to do at least two things to avoid your server's security policy (setting the program SUID root, and disabling SELinux).

Answer (score 1):

Apache may be configured so it could have been run from a chroot jail.  In that case /etc/shadow would not be available.

http://www.faqs.org/docs/securing/chap29sec254.html

Comment: no, i don't install apache in chroot. also if i try to read /etc/passwd, this snippets code works successfully.

Comment: Have the program `stat()` the file.  If it fails, print out the error number and the string (`int errnum = errno; printf("%d: %s<br />\n", errnum, strerror(errnum));`, capturing `errno` before it gets a chance to change.  If the `stat()` succeeds, I'll be modestly surprised; however, you should print the owner, group, size, and mode of the file.  One other way `root` can fail to access a file is if it is on an NFS-mounted file system.  However, it is extremely improbable that `/etc` would be NFS-mounted.  You might be running into some 'capability issues', but tracking that will be hairy!

Comment: ooh! this problem solved with setenforce 0!

another question now, is this code have security problem? means get users password with suid in a shared hosting ? and also turn of selinux?

Answer (score 0):

This problem can solved with `setenforce 0` to stop selinux stop.